# Active Directory in Asp.net core

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, active-directory, ldap

I already posted a question before and none answer so I thought I must add more info for my problem , so my problem is I don't know how to search user from AD I am trying to find solution but with no success most of the developper work with .net none of them with asp.net core .. here is what I did so far
Note : I am new I didn't work with AD before this is my first try

```
public class ADController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Find()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Find(FindViewModel model)
    {
        DirectoryEntry entry = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://<full user name>,<Users>,<domain component>");

        DirectorySearcher searcher;
        SearchResultCollection results;

        searcher = new DirectorySearcher(entry);

        searcher.Filter = "(&(objectClass=user)(displayname=*))";
        searcher.SearchScope = SearchScope.Subtree;

        using (searcher)
        {
            results = searcher.FindAll();

            foreach (SearchResult result in results)
            {
                string searchOK = result.Properties["displayname"][0].ToString();
                //objects.Add(searchOK);
            }
        }
        return View();
    }
}
```

```
public class FindViewModel
{
    [Display(Name = "UserActiveDirectory")]
    public string UserAD { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: What happens when you run this code? Error? Wrong result? You are returning a View without a model, are you sure the AD query is not working?

Comment: I did not run it because I don't have any clue how or where to stock the return of the data Active Directory , and that's why I am asking I also didnt create a razor page for the same issue

Comment: Your question states: "*my problem is I don't know how to search user from AD*". But now it sounds like you don't know how controllers and views work. If that is the case then just go through a getting started tutorial, it will be time well spent.

Comment: I think there misunderstanding I already have a full project .net core created by myself but my problem that I don't know how to get user from AD , I know that user in AD are object and I did not use object before , so how to get them , I already use MVC and it run perfectly ..

Comment: OK, then see my first comment.

Comment: let me be clear I want to create field where to write username then press submit to get that user if he exist in the AD my problem that those user in AD are object I can't get them into string so how to do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your requirements are a bit unclear, but I am assuming that:

1. You want to pass a username to your controller
2. Find that user in AD,
3. Pass the `displayName` of the found user to your view

If that's the case, then:

First, since you only need to pass a single string into your controller, there's no benefit to using a class as the parameter. Just use a single string:

```
public IActionResult Find(string username)
```

Then you need to use the username in your filter. There is no attribute called "username", but that most often refers to the `sAMAccountName`. However it could also refer to the `userPrincipalName`, which has the format of `username@example.com`. But I'll assume `sAMAccountName`.

Just `(objectClass=user)` is oddly not enough to limit the search to just user accounts. Computer objects, for example, have an `objectClass` of `user`. So if you want to limit the search to only user accounts, you need to also include `(objectCategory=person)`.

```
searcher.Filter = $"(&(objectClass=user)(objectCategory=person)(sAMAccountName={username}))";
```

The `SearchScope` is `Subtree` by default, so you don't need this line:

```
searcher.SearchScope = SearchScope.Subtree;
```

You should also use the [`PropertiesToLoad`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.directoryservices.directorysearcher.propertiestoload) collection because, if you don't, it will return every attribute. So put only the attributes you plan on using there:

```
searcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("displayName");
```

Since you're searching by `sAMAccountName`, which is guaranteed to be unique on the domain, you can use `FindOne()` instead of `FindAll()`, since you know there can only be one result (or none).

```
var result = searcher.FindOne();
```

If `result` is not `null`, that means the user was found and you can pass the `displayName` to the view:

```
if (result != null) {
    string displayName = (string) result.Properties["displayname"][0];
    return View(displayName);
}
```

Otherwise, don't pass anything to the view, and you will have to handle that case in the view.

Altogether, that looks like this:

```
public IActionResult Find(string username)
{
    var entry = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://<full user name>,<Users>,<domain component>");

    var searcher = new DirectorySearcher(entry) {
        Filter = $"(&(objectClass=user)(objectCategory=person)(sAMAccountName={username}))",
        PropertiesToLoad = { "displayName" }
    };

    var result = searcher.FindOne();
    
    if (result != null) {
        string displayName = (string) result.Properties["displayname"][0];
        return View(displayName);
    }
    
    return View();
}
```

You may still have to make some updates depending on your actual requirements, but this should get you started.

Comment: does the username refere to the modele userAD ?

Comment: another quick question do I need to connect to a specific user to see the others users in the domain ??

Comment: `username` refers to the value passed into the controller from the browser. e.g. `/find?username=MyUsername`

Comment: *"do I need to connect to a specific user to see the others users in the domain ?"* - You need to connect *as* a specific user. But if that query already works as-is with no errors, then you're already authenticated and you can read anything on the domain.